# Walker_Nav_Menu doesn't work in wp_page_menu_args filter

Tags: filters, walker

I need to hide certain nav items from the menu (based on the password protection functionality) and I'm having trouble getting my custom Walker to work. In fact, I can't even get the standard Walker_Nav_Menu to work when I add it via a filter.

I've created a plugin as follows:

```
<?php
function myplugin_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['walker'] = new Walker_Nav_Menu;
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'myplugin_page_menu_args' );
?>
```

There's no other code in the plugin file, just those 6 lines. I've added this plugin to a brand new install of WordPress (http://dev.matt-howe.co.uk/wordpress/) and the menu rendering is completely broken - all the items are on the same level, and none of them have any text. The right number of `<li>` elements are generated, and the ids are correct, but the rest is wrong.

I've tried using a custom class with a .walk() method, as so:

```
class myplugin_walker {
    function walk ( $elements, $to_depth ) {
        return 'test';
    }
}

function myplugin_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['walker'] = new myplugin_walker;
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'myplugin_page_menu_args' );
```

This works exactly as expected - the menu renders as 'test'. But trying to use either my own class which extends `Walker_Nav_Menu`, or the core `Walker_Nav_Menu` class itself, results in a flat list of empty `<li>` tags.

I've tried a few other ways to achieve the same result - I've tried adding filters for `wp_nav_menu_objects` and `wp_get_nav_menu_items` but neither of my functions seem to get called at all.

Am I barking up the wrong tree here - is this something that won't work as part of a plugin, and needs to be elsewhere in the code? Or am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Old Q, but I'll give my 2 cents.

1. The walker class should inherit `Walker_Page`, not `Walker_Nav_Menu` as is usually the case with guides on the 'net.
2. The `$item` object is a [Post Object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post), containing `post_title` and `ID`. To output the URL, you need to call `get_permalink($item-ID)`. Regarding `$item->url`, it will be unset.
3. Both `theme_location` and `fallback_cb` need to be non-present in the `$args` array given to `wp_nav_menu`.